# Problems with SourceGraph (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I try to visualize an existing Haskell code base with SourceGraph.

```
SourceGraph mycabal.cabal
```

But all I get are error messages like this:

```
Could not parse source file ./src/mysource.hs
SourceGraph: Could not find data file templates/default.html
```

Any hints what to do or where to look for documentation?

The only documentation I have found so far is this one: http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/SourceGraph/SourceGraph.html which unfortunately only consists of catchy images but with no hints how to produce them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your immediate question, it seems like the best documentation here is the source: http://code.haskell.org/SourceGraph/

I tried it on a repository of my own, and ran into the parsing issue, too. This is haskell-src-exts failing to parse a module. The following patch shows the actual error:

```
--- Parsing.hs  2013-02-14 12:59:34.000000000 +0100
+++ ../SourceGraph-0.7.0.5-fixed/Parsing.hs 2014-04-08 20:49:54.000000000 +0200
@@ -64,7 +64,7 @@
 parseFile       :: FileContents -> Either FilePath Module
 parseFile (p,f) = case (parseFileContentsWithMode mode f) of
                     (ParseOk hs) -> Right hs
-                    _            -> Left p
+                    x            -> Left $ p ++ ": " ++ show x
     where
       mode = defaultParseMode { parseFilename = p
                               , fixities = Nothing
```

It turns out that most of my failing modules failed because "MultiParamTypeClasses is not enabled". This is apparently haskell-src-exts being rightfully strict, while ghc is happy without the MultiParamTypeClasses extension: https://github.com/haskell-suite/haskell-src-exts/issues/29

So as a quick fix, try adding

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

at the top of your failing modules.

Comment: unfortunately the quick fix didn't help and I didn't figure yet out how to patch and reinstall SourceGraph via cabal. Neverthless thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just ran into a similar issue, so I thought I'd document here what I did. I put my changes in a patch file.
https://gist.github.com/ivanperez-keera/b398ce71a22e8a4849f3

```
cabal sandbox init
cabal unpack SourceGraph
wget https://gist.githubusercontent.com/ivanperez-keera/b398ce71a22e8a4849f3/raw/bf26ffc45564934c0f175e7619ded8a299a9b7d5/verbose-sourcegraph.patch
cd SourceGraph-0.7.0.6/
patch -i ../verbose-sourcegraph.patch
cd ..
cabal install SourceGraph-0.7.0.6/
```

Most of the "errors" in my files where due to bang patterns and multi param type classes. There must be a better solution to make SourceGraph's parse mode default to the same as GHC.